# How to fix the unknown property: 'scroll-snap-align' error in visual studio code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, frontend, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to add a scroll snap so that each section snaps to the center of the page but i'm getting an unknown property error in VS code so i can't apply it to my code. Is it possible to use scroll-padding-top and scroll-snap-align somehow? do i need an extension maybe?

I've updated to the latest version 1.30.2 but still no joy, i was going to use the depreciated versions of scroll but that didn't seem sensible.

/*parent container*/

```
.container {
display: flex;
flex-flow: column nowrap;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow-x: hidden;
scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
scroll-padding-top: 150px;
}
```

/*for the child elements*/

```
section {
height: 100vh;
scroll-snap-align:start;
}
```

i expected the code to snap each section 150px from the top allowing for the menu but nothing happens...

Comment: Can you provide more information about your workflow, build process, etc.? VS Code (like any IDE) will not prevent you from saving a file just because of code linting warnings.

Comment: Its plain old VS Code out of the box, the only extension i use is emmet and one for github @JonUleis - so i made the container height the same as the section height and it worked, it still gives the error message in problems, but works all the same. Appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Uleis was right, it did work, for some reason VS Code didn't seem to recognise the feature but it worked fine.

Comment: It still giving a linting error is not a  satisfactory resolution imo.